# Can't get nav to be centered

Tags: html, css

I cannot get my nav to be centered on my website. Here is my code that I have tried to get working:

```css
a:link { color: gold; }
a:visited { color: gold; }

a:hover { color: gold; }
.class1 {
  background-color: navy;
}
.class2 {
  background-color: black;
}
div p {
  background-color: navy;
}
header h1 {
  background-color: navy;
}
#idAttrubite1 {
  color: gold;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
#idAttrubite2 {
  color: gold;
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  color: gold;
  background-color: navy;
}
h1 {
  background-color: navy;
  color: gold;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: gold;
  background-color: navy;
  text-align: left;
}
h3 {
  background-color: navy;
  color: gold;
}
ul {
  background-color: navy;
  color: gold;
}
li {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", SansSerif, Tahoma, serif;
}
body {
  background-color: navy;
}

footer {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 1em;
}
header {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: navy;
}
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: navy;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
p img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  padding-top: 250px;
  padding-right: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

#center {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

form {
  color: gold;
}
nav a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
  border: 3px outset gold;
  background-color: navy;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml%22%3E?">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>About My Dogs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <img src="ellielick.jpg" height="700" />
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="Dogs.html">Dogs</a>
    <a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a>
    <a href="form.html">Form</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h2><br/><br/>My Dogs</h2>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2020 Dogs - Kolton Ukena - Phone: 316-617-6853
      <br/>
      <a href="mailto:kukena@my.wctc.edu">kukena@my.wctc.edu</a>
    </footer>
  </main>
</body>
```

I have tried floats, I have also tried margins, and I have tried padding. What should I try next? I am working on this for my final for my web development class.

Comment: Probably a good idea to scrub your email/phone and other info like that out of your question/code before posting

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the nav in a UL and the links in li's (more semantic that way anyway).

Example:

```
   <nav>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Dogs.html">Dogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
        <li><a href="form.html">Form</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul#nav{
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
}
nav ul#nav li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```